# Access spread worksheet by region

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a spread worksheet problem by using Microsoft Access.
I have a table that is a master file. The columns are ID, Name, department, Revenue, ...., Region

Another table where I just store the Region name, only this column, and it has 104 countries (such as the USA, China, Taiwan, England......)

|When I use access to link these two files, I want to spread the master file by region and create 104 excel file.

I know it is easy to use Excel VBA code to do it, and it has been done.
but can I use Microsoft access to do this work without coding?

After linking these two files, it cannot spread to be an individual table by region.

Can someone teach me the method?

Comment: You mean that you want to create multiple excel files, one for each country?  And each excel file should have columns from the Master table where Region equals the country?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you will certainly need VBA or macros (which I consider code) to accomplish this task.  Access can indeed export queried data to an excel file without any code by using the data export wizards.  However, if you need a separate file for each value in a table, there is no automatic way to do that and so it would require writing code which enumerates (i.e. loops through) each data row and generates separate excel files.

Comment: thanks @CPerkins, so access cannot do the looping? your understand is correct.

Comment: Access can do the looping, but you asked "without coding".  Access could not do looping without code.